# How to remove auto generated <p> tag inside text-angular?

Tags: angularjs, textangular

I am trying to use text-angular but after every line changes it will auto-generate new

tag for every new line.

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation, depending on the version you are using, it might be as simple as adding the `taDefaultWrap`-Attribute and specifying which wrapping-mode you want., e.g.:

```
<text-angular ng-model="htmlVariable" ta-default-wrap="div"></text-angular>
```

Documention can be found here: https://github.com/textAngular/textAngular/wiki/Directives

Relevant part from their website:

> taDefaultWrap: The name of a HTML tag that will wrap each line by
>   default.

It was implemented due to a request which can be found here:
[Option to disable default p wrapping](https://github.com/textAngular/textAngular/issues/131)

The request included the following examples which should work:

```
ta-default-wrap="h2"
ta-default-wrap="div"
ta-default-wrap=""   <!-- no tag for new line -->
```